# Prove that (n!+1) is not divisible by any natural number between 2 and n.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factorial

I tried this question solving by mathematical induction. But no luck
Is there is any easy way to prove that?

Comment: What is the remainder when $n!$ is divided by any number between $2$ and $n$?

Comment: Hint:  If $k > 1$ and $k\mid m$ then $k\not \mid m+1$.

Comment: Hint:  $n!$  *IS* divisible by *EVERY* natural number between $2$ and $n$.

Comment: Hint:  If $k|m$ then $k| b + km \iff k|b$.  So if $k|m$ and $k\not \mid b$ then $k\not \mid m + b$.  Let $m = n!$ and $b=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:   If $k|m$ and $k> 1$ then $k\not \mid m+1$.

> Pf:  Do we need to prove it?  If $m = bk$ for some integer $b$ then $m+1 = bk + 1$ and $\frac {m+1}k = b + \frac 1k$ which is *not* an integer.

And if $2\le k \le n$ then $n! = 1*2*........ * n = \prod_{j:1\le j \le n} j$. So $k$ is between $2.... n$ then it is one of the factors of $n!$.

FORMAL ANSWER (don't read this)

> if $2\le k \le n$ then $k$ is a factor of $n! = 1*2*.....*n$.  And so $\frac {n!}k$ is an integer.  Lets call $\frac {n!}k :=M$.  Then $n! = Mk$.  So $n!+1 = Mk + 1$ and $\frac {n!+1}k = \frac {Mk+1}k = M + \frac 1k$.  But $k > 1$ so $\frac 1k$ is not an integer.  So $M + \frac 1k$ is not an integer.  So $k\not \mid n! + 1$.

Or a single-line unbelievably short proof:

> $n!$ is divisible by all natural number $2$ to $n$ and $1$ is not divisible by any.  So $n!+1$ is not divisible by any.

QED

Answer (score 1):

I never want to say *don't* use induction but...  you shouldn't.

But I never want to say don't so:

BASE CASE:  $n=2$

$2! + 1=3$. and $2\not \mid 3$.

INDUCTION STEP:

If $k!+1$ is not divisible but any natural number between $2$ and $k$.

Then $(k+1)! + 1 = k!(k+1) + 1= k\cdot k! + k! + 1= k\cdot k! + (k!+1)$.  Now any natural number between $2$ and $k$ *will* divide* $k\cdot k!$ but will not divide $k!+1$ so it will not divide $k\cdot k! + (k!+1)$.

And  $k+1$ does divide $k!(k+1)$ but does not divide $1$.  SO $k+1$ does not divide $k!(k+1) + 1$.

So no natural number between $2$ and $k+1$ will divide $(k+1)!$.  So that is the induction step.

......

SO it can be proven by induction.  And it wasn't as hard as I thought it would be.  But it wasn't what I'd call *easy*.

There is a much easier and direct prove that is based on the same idea:

> $n!$ is divisible by all natural numbers between $2$ and $n$ and $1$ is not.  So $n! + 1$ is not.  End of proof.  QED.